# Query by type using Linq on an nHibernate table by sub-class structure

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have quite a complex entity structure where several classes inherit from a base class, hence choosing a table per-subclass structure in nhibernate.

BaseProject

```
ProjectA : BaseProject  
ProjectB : BaseProject  
ProjectC : BaseProject  
ProjectD : BaseProject
```

I want to search where one of the criteria will be ProjectType. I'm trying to avoid writing a seperate query specification for each ProjectType.

Does anyone know how this might be achieved? Is it even something Linq to nHibernate can do, as I think it isn't complete yet.

I was expecting something like `x => x.GetType() == typeof(ProjectTypeA)` to work but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way you've described is the only way to do this using the current Linq provider. You'll need to expose a property (likely an enumeration) mapped with NHibernate that is exposed by each sub class. One useful trick is to map this property with `update=false` to ensure it is never changed.

You can see my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451395/nhibernate-linq-nhibernate-queryexception-could-not-resolve-property-profile/3467077#3467077) for further details.